# Punctuation of a question that ends with a statement

Tags: punctuation

How would you punctuate this question, which ends as a statement:

> Where is Mom I need to talk to her

Comment: This is actually a run-on sentence, and would need to be split into two sentences anyway if grammar is important.

Answer (score 27):

*Where is Mom? I need to talk to her.*

Comment: To make it clear.  You would split this into two sentences?

Comment: @DavidM - Yes, this particular passage should be split into two sentences, unless you're going for some kind of nonstandard literary effect.

Comment: Thanks!  And, if it were a quotation you would offset it without splitting?  "Where is Mom?" she wondered, needing to talk to her.

Comment: If it were a quotation I suppose you could either split it into two sentences, or quote the first part and paraphrase the last, as you have done. When authors and journalists assign punctuation to spoken quotations, they usually try to do it in the way that makes the most sense without distorting what the speaker has said.

Comment: @DavidM If it's a *quotation*, use the punctuation from the original, possibly with sprinkling of "sic". If it's *direct speech*, you can punctuate as you please because people (other than [Victor Borge](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bpIbdZhrzA)) don't punctuate their speech.  "Where is mom?  I need to talk to her," she said.  ("I don't know fssst pwt what you need to talk to her about quack spop," said Victor.)

Comment: @DavidR, +10 for the Victor Borge references!

Comment: @DavidM, not quite. He wouldn't “split it up into two sentences”—it already _is_ two sentences. He'd just punctuate it accordingly.

Answer (score -4):

Where is Mom, I need to talk to her?

Comment: No. This is just wrong, unless “I need to talk to her?” is also a question, which it wouldn't be in about 99.9% of actual use cases.

Comment: Where? is Mom I need, to talk; to her?